# MS Access VBA - How to execute an event when MouseMove leave an object

Tags: vba, ms-access, onmousemove

I have a button where i set a MouseMouse Event like this:

```
Private Sub button1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
txtbox.value = "ok"
End Sub
```

When the mouse leave this button, i want to change the txtbox.value..
How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Configure an appropriate `MouseMove` event handler for the area that the cursor will move into upon leaving the button, e.g.:

```
Private Sub Detail_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    txtbox.Value = Null
End Sub
```

Comment: how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Draw a rectangle, set to Visible=False, around the button.  Then create a Mouse Move event that enables the rectangle, which also has a Mouse Move event.  There is some additional handling to reset controls, but here are the basics:

Controls:

- Button1
- Box1
- Text1

```
    Private Sub Box1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single) 
      Me.Text1.SetFocus  
      Me.Text1.Text = "OK"
    End Sub 

    Private Sub Button1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
      Me.Box1.Visible = True
    End Sub
```

[image]